# Is the objective function in Lagrange multipliers a convex function?

Tags: math, optimization

Is the objective function in Lagrange multipliers a convex function?

personally, I guess not. Coz the dual function of the primal function must be a concave function, that is why we feel hard to get the result when the objective function of the primal problem is not convex?

Is my understanding correct?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a better fit for [math.se].

Comment: In general, the Lagrange function will not be convex.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no limitation on the objective function. 
Consider the optimization problem:

> maximize f(x, y) subject to g(x, y) = 0.
>   If f and g have continuous first partial derivatives, then we can define 
>   L(x,y,lambda) = f(x,y)-lambda*g(x,y)
>   for more information, see Lagrange_multiplier in [wiki]